# Script gets stopped when running in background

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 terminal-only.

I'm currently trying to run a python script in the background so I can continue using the terminal. However, after running the script and I try do something, the script stops.

Example:

```
jack2022@jack2022:~/Documents/Project4$ python3 run.py > /dev/null &
[1] 5812
jack2022@jack2022:~/Documents/Project4$ cd ..
jack2022@jack2022:~/Documents$ cd Project4/

[1]+  Stopped       python3 run.py > /dev/null
jack2022@jack2022:~/Documents/Project4$
```

What's happening here? How can I make it so the script runs FULLY in the background? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

---------- UPDATE ----------

**NOTE:** Other python scripts are successfully running in the background, so I know run.py itself is the problem. Also, me doing something while run.py is running isn't what's stopping it – if I leave it running it'll stop within like 10s. I've narrowed down exactly which line run.py gets stopped at:

```
from pyloudness import get_loudness #the function i'm importing

...

loudness_stats = get_loudness(file) #run.py stops at this line
```

I've looked through the [pyloudness pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/pyloudness/) and found that it states ffmpeg as a prerequisite for pyloudness – I have the latest version of ffmpeg installed on my Ubuntu machine. Plus, the python script runs perfectly fine when not run in the background.

Comment: Does this only happen with `run.py` or with other things as well? Does it work as expected if you run `sleep 60 &` for example? How about a different python script? Does `run.py` try to read input?

Comment: I tested another python script and it seems to be working just fine and run.py doesn't read input. But now I know run.py is the problem.

Comment: Alright I narrowed down to exactly what line is making run.py stop. Added details in OP

Comment: perhaps you could add the output of just `python3 run.py` instead of sending the output to /dev/null

Comment: @rtaft Wait what do you mean by add the output? run.py also stops running when I redirect the output to a file, like```python3 run.py > output.txt &```. However, run.py does work when the output is put to the terminal.

Comment: `python3 run.py &> output.txt &` to get the error output in the logfile too

Comment: Try if it helps with `nohup` like this or something similar: `nuhup python3 run.py > /dev/null &`. See `man nohup`.

Comment: @sudodus Can confirm that ```nohup python3 run.py > /dev/null &``` worked for me – run.py is running the background properly. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @THEMOUNTAINSANDTHESKIES, You are welcome, I'm glad I could help you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if it helps with `nohup` like this or something similar:

```
nohup python3 run.py > /dev/null &
```

See `man nohup`

> ```
> NAME
>    nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
>
> SYNOPSIS
>    nohup COMMAND [ARG]...
>    nohup OPTION
>
> DESCRIPTION
>    Run COMMAND, ignoring hangup signals.
>
>    --help display this help and exit
>
>    --version
>           output version information and exit
>
>    If  standard  input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file.
>    If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if  pos‐
>    sible,  '$HOME/nohup.out'  otherwise.  If standard error is a terminal,
>    redirect it to standard output.  To save output  to  FILE,  use  'nohup
>    COMMAND > FILE'.
>
>    NOTE:  your  shell  may  have  its  own version of nohup, which usually
>    supersedes the version described here.  Please refer  to  your  shell's
>    documentation for details about the options it supports.
> ```